# Perl regexp how to get the file name out?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this directory path:

```
\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1
```

How can I get the file name `testQEM.txt` from the above string?

I use this:

```
$file =~ /(.+\\)(.+\..+)(\\.+)/;
```

But get this result:

```
file = testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM
```

Thanks,

Jirong

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand, as paths cannot have a file node half way through them! Have multiple paths got concatenated somehow?

Anyway, I suggest you work though the path looking for the first node that validates as a real file using [`-f`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Here is an example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = '\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1';

my @path = split /\\/, $path;
my $file = shift @path;
$file .= '\\'.shift @path until -f $file or @path == 0;

print "$file\n";
```

Comment: This string is generated by ClearCase, the original string is this "M:\ccadm01_ABC_BUILD\Informatica_AVOB\ABC_infa\dummy@@\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1". I want to reconstruct the real file like this: M:\ccadm01_ABC_BUILD\Informatica_AVOB\ABC_infa\dummy\testQEM.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
/[^\\]+\.[^\\]+/
```

Capture anything separated by a `.` between two backslashes.  Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Right, but can you write the complete line of code to get that testQEM.txt from the above string?

Comment: It's literally the same as what you wrote, but with this regex instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit difficult, as directory names can contain contain periods. This is especially true for *nix Systems, but is valid under Windows as well.

Therefore, each possible subpath has to be tested iteratively for file-ness.

I'd maybe try something like this:

```
my $file;
my $weirdPath = q(/main/ABC_PRD/ABC_QEM/1/testQEM.txt/main/ABC_QEM/1);
my @parts = split m{/} $weirdPath;

for my $i (0 .. $#parts) {
   my $path = join "/", @parts[0 .. $i];
   if (-f $path) { # optionally "not -d $path"
     $file = $parts[$i];
     last;
   }
}
print "file=$file\n"; # "file=testQEM.txt\n"
```

I `split` the weird path at all slashes (change to backslashes if interoperability is not an issue for you). Then I join the first `$i+1` elements together and test if the path is a normal file. If so, I store the last part of the path and exit the loop.

If you can guarantee that the file is the only part of the path that contains periods, then using one of the other solutions will be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $file = '\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1';
my ($result) = $file =~ /\\([^\\]+\.[^\\]+)\\/;
```

Parentheses around $result force the list context on the right hand side expression, which in turn returns what matches in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much! The result is right but I don't understand the expression, will study.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `/(?=[^\\]+\.)([^\\]+)/`

```
my $path = '\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1';
print $1 if $path =~ /(?=[^\\]+\.)([^\\]+)/;
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/3xqQj).

Answer (score 0):

```
>echo "\main\ABC_PRD\ABC_QEM\1\testQEM.txt\main\ABC_QEM\1"|perl -pi -e "s/.*([\\][a-zA-Z]*\.txt).*/\1/"
\testQEM.txt
```

Comment: The file can be any extension,not just .txt. And please give me a complete line of perl code. This has to be done inside a perl script.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you may comprehend principle of regexp Backtracking ，such as how  * and + to work.
you only make a little change about your regexp as:

```
/(.+\\)(.+\..+?)(\\.+)/
```